# Is there a way to config Python's JSON library to ignore fields that have null values when calling json.loads()?

Tags: python, json

Python version 2.7

```
>>> json.loads('{"key":null,"key2":"yyy"}')
{u'key2': u'yyy', u'key': None}
```

The above is the default behaviour. What I want is the result to become:

```
{u'key2': u'yyy'}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you will have to process the data yourself after it is deserialized.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can filter the result after loading:

```
res = json.loads(json_value)
res = {k: v for k, v in res.iteritems() if v is not None}
```

Or you can do this in the `object_hook` callable:

```
def remove_nulls(d):
    return {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is not None}

res = json.loads(json_value, object_hook=remove_nulls)
```

which will handle recursive dictionaries too.

For Python 3, use `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()` to efficiently enumerate the keys and values of the dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_value = '{"key":null,"key2":"yyy"}'
>>> def remove_nulls(d):
...     return {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is not None}
... 
>>> json.loads(json_value, object_hook=remove_nulls)
{u'key2': u'yyy'}
>>> json_value = '{"key":null,"key2":"yyy", "key3":{"foo":null}}'
>>> json.loads(json_value, object_hook=remove_nulls)
{u'key3': {}, u'key2': u'yyy'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following solution before finding this question. Using `object_hook` is better, but in case you need to remove all nested elements of an already parsed JSON, you can use the following recursive function:

```
def remove_nulls (d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for  k, v in list(d.items()):
            if v is None:
                del d[k]
            else:
                remove_nulls(v)
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            remove_nulls(v)
    return d
```

Notice that it will change your existing dictionary.